# PYTHON: List of Words; Looking to Create All Perumtations of The Words (Similar To Numbers) BUT Limit to 3 Words Per Solution:

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to display all possible permutations of a list of words, for example if I have one two three I want to get:

one two three
one three two
three two one
...

All perumtations. HOWEVER if i have all numbers written out in English (zero - nine) I STILL WANT TO LIMIT to only 3 words per solution...

I need to be able to do this for any set of words.

I'm sure its probably fairly simple using something like itertools.combinations but I can't quite get the syntax right. So i dont have any code yet.

Comment: Make sure to show us what youve tried already

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
import itertools
input_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
print(list(itertools.islice(itertools.permutations(input_list), 3)))
```